# Align div Elements with content within table cell

Tags: html, css

I am having problem aligning div elements in a table cell. Specially when the div element contains content in the CSS. It seems the div containing content drops below the other divs for a reason that I could not figure out, as shown in the image below. I have created a minimum example of the problem where I want the green div to align vertically with the other two divs inside the td element.

```css
tr {
  height: 30px;
}

td {
  width: 100px
}

.l1 {
  height: 30px;
  width: 10px;
  background: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}

.l2 {
  height: 30px;
  width: 10px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.toggle {
  height: 30px;
  width: 20px;
  background: green;
  display: inline-block;
}

.toggle:before {
  content: "\229F";
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="level2">
          <div class="l1"></div>
          <div class="l2"></div>
          <div class="toggle"></div>
        </td>
        <td>Task 1</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You are working with `inline-block` elements here, so you need to apply some `vertical-align`. (Or use a more modern layout system like flexbox in the first place.)

Comment: You don't want to use a **block-level element** inside a table. Rather use flexbox for these kind of things.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding vertical-align: top; to the .toggle class

```css
tr {
  height: 30px;
}

td {
  width: 100px
}

.l1 {
  height: 30px;
  width: 10px;
  background: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}

.l2 {
  height: 30px;
  width: 10px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.toggle {
  height: 30px;
  width: 20px;
  background: green;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.toggle:before {
  content: "\229F";
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="level2">
          <div class="l1"></div>
          <div class="l2"></div>
          <div class="toggle"></div>
        </td>
        <td>Task 1</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you're already specifying `display: inline-block;` for the `div`s inside the `td.level2` column, the easiest possible solution here is to use `vertical-align: middle;` to vertically center those `div`s.

Here's a live demo:

```css
/** vertically center all the DIVs inside the column with class "level2" */
td.level2 > div {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

tr {
  height: 30px;
}

td {
  width: 100px
}

.l1 {
  height: 30px;
  width: 10px;
  background: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}

.l2 {
  height: 30px;
  width: 10px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.toggle {
  height: 30px;
  width: 20px;
  background: green;
  display: inline-block;
}

.toggle:before {
  content: "\229F";
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="level2">
          <div class="l1"></div>
          <div class="l2"></div>
          <div class="toggle"></div>
        </td>
        <td>Task 1</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

> Learn more about [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) rule on MDN.

Answer (score 0):

The text content inside the green element has whitespace included, as all inline text content does. This extends outside the green element. You can change that with the overflow property.

```css
tr {
  height: 30px;
}

td {
  width: 100px
}

.l1 {
  height: 30px;
  width: 10px;
  background: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}

.l2 {
  height: 30px;
  width: 10px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.toggle {
  height: 30px;
  width: 20px;
  background: green;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden; /* <------------ here */
}

.toggle:before {
  content: "\229F";
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="level2">
          <div class="l1"></div>
          <div class="l2"></div>
          <div class="toggle"></div>
        </td>
        <td>Task 1</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add `position: absolute` to `:before`

```css
tr {
  height: 30px;
}

td {
  width: 100px
}

.l1 {
  height: 30px;
  width: 10px;
  background: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}

.l2 {
  height: 30px;
  width: 10px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.toggle {
  height: 30px;
  width: 20px;
  background: green;
  display: inline-block;
}

.toggle:before {
  content: "\229F";
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="level2">
          <div class="l1"></div>
          <div class="l2"></div>
          <div class="toggle"></div>
        </td>
        <td>Task 1</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You should copy the snippet down here and demonstrate your solution.

Answer (score 0):

simply add the first two in a container then add display flex to `level2` then set `flex-direction` to column

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="l1"></div>
  <div class="l2"></div>
</div>
<div class="toggle"></div>

.level2 {
   display: flex;
}
```

```css
tr{
    height: 30px;
  
}

td{
    width: 100px;
 
}

.l1{
    height:30px;
    width:10px;
    background:blue;
    display:inline-block;
}

.l2{
    height:30px;
    width:10px;
    background:red;
    display:inline-block;
}

.level2 {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}

.toggle{
    height:30px;
    width:20px;
    background:green;
    display:inline-block;
    
}


.toggle:before{
    content:"\229F";
}
```

```html
<body>
        <div class="container">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="level2">
                        <div class="container">
                          <div class="l1"></div>
              <div class="l2"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="toggle"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td>Task 1</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
```